# Apollo Server 2.x express middleware

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-server

I am using Apollo Server 2.x (Not Apollo Server Express)

I like to add in some express middlewares

In such circumstances, do i need to migrate to use apollo-server-express in order to add in express middlewares? Or can apollo server 2.x accomodate express middlewares

If apollo server 2.x, can point me to the docs how i can use apollo server 2.x with express middleware?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

While `apollo-server` does utilize `express` under the hood, it intentionally does not provide a way to configure additional middleware. The intent is for its use of `express` to be transparent -- it could use `hapi` or some other library in the future without breaking existing implementations. If you need to integrate `apollo-server` with `express`, you should use `apollo-server-express`. Migrating is simple:

**apollo-server**

```
const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

const port = 4000;

server.listen({ port });
```

**apollo-server-express**

```
const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

const app = express();
server.applyMiddleware({ app });

const port = 4000;

app.listen({ port });
```